# RowDataBound command error

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I get the same error for both buttons.  I think it is the Partial `RowDataBound` command:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Error code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

```
public void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@datetime"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col1"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol1")).Text;
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col2"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol2")).Text;
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["@col3"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol3")).Text;
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public void btntotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow GR in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox TempTxt1 = (TextBox)GR.FindControl("txt1");
        TextBox TempTxt2 = (TextBox)GR.FindControl("txt2");
        TextBox TempTxt3 = (TextBox)GR.FindControl("txt3");
        TempTxt1.Text = Convert.ToString(TempTxt1);
        TempTxt2.Text = Convert.ToString(TempTxt2);
        TempTxt3.Text = Convert.ToString(TempTxt3);
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataKeyNames="idt" 
    OnDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    showfooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idt" HeaderText="idt" Readonly="true" SortExpression="idt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="datetime" SortExpression="datetime" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol1" text="col1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFootercol1" text="col1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col2">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol2" text="col2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col2") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFootercol2" text="col2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col3">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol3" text="col3" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("col3") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFootercol3"  text="col3" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton OnClick="btninsert_Click"  ID="btninsert" runat="server" >Insert Into</asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAllTotal" Text="Total" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton OnClick="btntotal_Click"  ID="btntotal" runat="server" >Total</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connone %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test];
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] ([datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) VALUES (@datetime,@col1,@col2,@col3);"
    runat="server">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="datetime" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col3" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The `RowDataBound` is empty, so why do you think that it's causing the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: The pointer to the row I think is not right. Both buttons give the same error.

Comment: You cannot access the `TextBoxes` in the `EditItemTemplate` from `btntotal_Click`. Only if the grid is in edit-mode. Therefore `TempTxt1.Text` causes the exception.

Comment: If I flip the textboxes with the labels? The output of the labels to the gridview would be messed up.

Comment: Is there another template to use with textboxes?